# Gradient color Raphael

Tags: raphael, gradient

When in Raphael I set color to `90-#7ADADD-#338A93` on path it becomes gradient. Then when I inspect element I can see it's `fill` property is set to something like: `url(#490-_7ADADD-_338A93)`.

If I try to change it to `90-#7ADADD-#338A93` it becomes black.
The question is how to change gradient color externally? How can I calculate this `url(#490-_7ADADD-_338A93)` from my original `90-#7ADADD-#338A93`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the full SVG source it might look something like this

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="490-_7ADADD-_338A93" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      ....
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <ellipse cx="200" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="url(#490-_7ADADD-_338A93)" />
</svg>
```

The `url(...)` part is actually a reference to a gradient defined in `defs`. If you change the reference to something that doesn't exist it will be displayed with a black fill.

The logical thing to do in Raphael is keep your gradient manipulation within the library. If you do...

```
path.attr({"fill": "90-#fff-#000"})
path.attr({"fill": "90-#ccc-#666"})
```

Then Raphael will insert a new `linearGradient` and reference it for you.

If you *really* need to manipulate the SVG source then you can do something like...

```
var gradient = document.getElementById('490-_7ADADD-_338A93');
var stops = gradient.querySelectorAll('stop');
stops[0].setAttribute("stop-color", "#c00");
stops[1].setAttribute("stop-color", "#00c");
```

But this will break VML compatibility (IE 8 or less).